# Dissolution of ionic compounds

Tags: ionic-compounds

Where can I find a table that lists the rates of dissolution of common ionic compounds like sodium chloride, potassium permanganate, and ammonium nitrate? Are there tables and equations that relate these rates with the temperature and concentration of the bulk solution?

Comment: Not sure that there *is* such a table, because the *rate* of dissolution depends so greatly on the form of the substance (massive, large crystals, nanoparticles), the state of hydration (anhydrous copper sulfate generally dissolves more slowly than the pentahydrate, if memory serves me right), agitation, etc.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I would assume temperature should have a massive effect though. In a way, I’ve always thought of temperature as a form of agitation. In that at high temperatures the kinetic energy from the motion of the solvent particles perturbs the diffusion layer enough to reduce its concentration and in turn lead to an increase in the rate of dissolution.

Comment: There would be too many nonlinear unknowns to have such a table  You would be lucky finding a dissolution study for a particular substance.

Answer (score 1):

No such table exists, because the rate of dissolution depends on the importance of the interface. I just would like to mention a case where this dissolution of $\ce{NaCl}$ is instantaneous. If you inject a dilute salty solution of usual soap in the base of a fuel burner, the flame will produce some clouds of amorphous $\ce{NaCl}$. If this smoke is collected, it is made of uncrystallized sodium chloride. Well, dipped into water, this thin $\ce{NaCl}$ powder is immediately dissolved, as Prof. Wendelin Stark, from ETHZ Zurich, has shown a couple of years ago.